# Get View ids in a for loop programatically?

Tags: android, view, android-resources, r.java-file, android-identifiers

I simply want to know . is there a way to create an id's using for loop

I have 10 buttons in xml . there id's are `button1,button2,button3... button10`  Now i create an **Array of Button** in `java class` and do it like this

```
public class Menu extends Activity
{
    Button[] arrayButton=new Button[10];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        for(int i=1 ; i<9 ; i++)
        {
            String abc = "but"+String.valueof(i);
            int x = Integer.parseInt(abc);


            Log.d("abc", abc);

            Log.d("x", String.valueOf(x) );

            //arrayButton[i] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x);  // giving error 

            //arrayButton[i].setText("Hello:");
        }
    }

}
```

I want to know how can i  do this kind of work . Getting all button using for loop to make my work faster and some time when i want to set the text of all the buttons .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `getResources().getIdentifier` like

```
String abc = "but"+String.valueof(i);
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(abc, "id", getPackageName());
arrayButton[i] = (Button) findViewById(resID );
arrayButton[i].setText("Hello:");
```

i.e. simply rewrite `init()` method as

```
private void init()
    {
        for(int i=1 ; i<9 ; i++)
        {
            String abc = "but"+String.valueof(i);
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(abc, "id", getPackageName());
            arrayButton[i] = (Button) findViewById(resID);
            arrayButton[i].setText("Hello:");
        }
    }
```

Or simple you may use

```
    int[] buttonIDs = new int[] {R.id.but1, R.id.but2, R.id.but3,R.id.but4, ... }
    for(int i=0; i<buttonIDs.length; i++) {
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(buttonIDs[i]);
        b.setText("Hello:" + b.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: Now if i want to open Activities like this how can i do it. i mean startActivity("Activity"+i).. in a for looop ....is it possible

Comment: @Nepster but you may start one activity at a time,Please describe exact situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know all the ids, you can simply use:

```
int [] ids = new int [] {R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, ...};
Button [] arrayButton = new Button[ids.length];

for(int i=0 ; i < arrayButton.length ; i++)
{
  arrayButton[i] = (Button) findViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

Or if you don't know them, use:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("btn1","id",getPackageName())
```

Comment: +1 Now if i want to open Activities like this how can i do it. i mean startActivity("Activity"+i).. in a for looop ....is it possible

Comment: The same way: Class [] classes = new Class [] {Activity1.class, Activity2.class, ...};

Comment: getResources().getClasses("btn1","id",getPackageName()) .. any other method like this..

Comment: No, you can't use this. It's only for resource identifiers.

Comment: Any other way like getting Classes or get classes under a PackageName

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**main.xm**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActvity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout lnrMain;
    private Button[] arrayButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lnrMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrMain);
        arrayButton=new Button[10];
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<lnrMain.getChildCount() ; i++)
        {
            arrayButton[i] = (Button) lnrMain.getChildAt(i);
            arrayButton[i].setText("Hello:"+(i+1));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper void like:

```
public static int getResourceID(Context mContext, String StrId) {
    return mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(StrId, "id", mContext.getPackageName());
}
```